# Sort W/YYYY date format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

How would you sort string from Mysql database, which has format:

```
W/YYYY
```

Example:

```
1/2020
1/2020
2/2020
3/2020
4/2020
4/2020
10/2020
11/2020
11/2020
30/2020
31/2020
```

I would like to get individual dates sorted by latest week number. For now I am using this SQL command to get individual dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `week` FROM `mytable`;
```

It is possible right in SQL, or PHP to get output like this?

```
31/2020
30/2020
11/2020
10/2020
4/2020
3/2020
2/2020
1/2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string functions.  For a descending sort:

```
order by right(week, 4) desc,
         substring_index(week, '/', 1) + 0 desc
```

An alternative method does not convert to a number:

```
order by right(week, 4) desc,
         length(week) desc,
         week desc
```

Comment: Due to how strings are converted to numbers, `right(week, 4) desc, week + 0 desc` should also work.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . I know.  But that is a fluke of the implicit conversion.  `cast(week as unsigned)` would generate an error.  It seems awkward to suggest something so close to generating an error, when there is an easy work-around.

Comment: Hmm.. `cast(week as unsigned)` works for me. But I get the point and would probably not use it in production code.